# Visual Studio 2015: When using C++ webview: Access violation writing location 0x00000000

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, webview, uwp, win-universal-app

I created a `C++` Blank App (Universal Windows) in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2. I added a `webview` and when running the app in Debug or Release mode, it crashes with error: `Access violation writing location 0x00000000.`

If I perform similar steps using `C#` or `Visual Basic`, I do not get the error. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue if I debug the `C++` app in **x86** arch on a **x64 machine** which OS build is 10586.318, Version 1511 and Windows SDK is also 10586. If you change your project's platform to **x64** or choose "**Start Without Debugging**", you can run your app successfully.

And as I've tested, this issue has been fixed in Windows Insider Preview **14316.rs1**, it's possible to be delivered in the following released version.

You're welcome to join the [Windows Insider Program](https://insider.windows.com/) and give us feedback on our latest work.